# AngularJS Material Design does not have Animations support, how to achieve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, animation, material-design

I am making a Hybrid App using AngularJS and want it to be based on the Material Design UI Principles. I have been reading about this on the google website. They have explained a lot about the natural animations that material should undergo. I am loving the demonstrations on this page.

http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

However, the supporting open source project Angular Material Design does not have any directives or provisions for these animations. How can I achieve this animations please guide.

I am planning to do it using CSS3 Animations. How should I use them and what should be the architecture, please suggest.

Comment: So @rahat-khanna, have you found a favorable solution to this?  I am in the same situation and I am considering 1) go with a mock material design framework like Angular Material, 2) don't bother with Material Design at all, or 3) go native.  I'd rather not go native, so I am leaning toward 1.

Comment: I think going 1 is only option if you do not want to go native. Moreover the CSS Frameworks mentioned in some answers have evolved and are mature now.

Comment: I checked the angular-material portal now and it looks like they have all the animations in now: https://material.angularjs.org/#/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you haven't decided already, Materialize (http://materializecss.com) is a Material Design based CSS framework that is very easy to use. It is structured similarly to Bootstrap. The animations have cubic easing that gives it the natural feel.

Comment: Although the link given by you is awesome, and they have done a wonderful stuff, but their javascript components are based on jQuery for which I cannot use them directly into my AngularJS project.

Comment: Agreed, big barrier to entry for materialize is that there are no angularjs directives for JS components.  Unfortunate as materiazlize is beautiful.

Comment: [There is now a project (Angular Materialize)](https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize) to create Angular directives for the Materialize framework.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will be any help to you but a CSS framework has been built based on Material Design http://material-ui.com

Comment: The same is there for Angular too - http://material.angularjs.org but I want to achieve natural animations like http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight

Answer (score 2):

You could use famo.us. Here's a proof of concept:

http://blog.aminjam.com/building-mobile-apps-with-famous-and-angular-material/

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material Project does not provide animations, but in general, for AngularJS, I've found following package very useful

> **[ng-fx](https://angularclass.github.io/ng-fx/)**

You can simply install this package and inject it as dependancy, and then adding animations is as simple as adding the specific classes to our HTML.

You still need go through material design guidelines and figure out which animations are suitable and where they should be used.

Answer (score -4):

Try using this

https://material.angularjs.org

"The Angular Material project is an implementation of Material Design in Angular.js. This project provides a set of reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components based on the Material Design system.

Similar to the Polymer project's Paper elements collection, Angular Material is supported internally at Google by the Angular.js, Material Design UX and other product teams."

Comment: Might be me, but the Angular Material project is explicitly mentioned in the question, the problem being there are no provisions for animations.